# Programming Principles and Practice using C++ while-loop drill. Can't find a way to exit the loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, exit

I'm going through Bjarne Stroustrup's 'Programming : Principles and Practice using C++" and I've got  a drill which tells me to write a program that consists of a while-loop that (each time around the loop) reads in two ints and then prints them and that it should exit when "|" is entered. I've written the program(I'm sure there's a easier way of writing it, but I've got the "gift" of overcomplicating things), but I can't find a way of exiting the loop. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{

    std::vector<int> answers;
    int answer;
    int intCounter=0;

    while(answers.size()<=2  )
    {

        if(answer=='|')
        {
            return 0;
        }
        std::cin>>answer;
        answers.push_back(answer);
        ++intCounter;

        if(intCounter==2)
        {
            for(int x : answers)
            {
                std::cout<<x<<'\n';
            }
            answers.clear();
            intCounter=0;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Basically if I write an if statement to check if answer is equal to '|', the compiler thinks i meant the int value of it(124 or something like that) and terminates the loop when I write 124, and that's clearly not what I want. I've tried to look over the internet for a way of converting an int into a char, but I haven't understood anything from there. The simplest solution would be the best.

Comment: take in the input as a `std::string` and then convert to an int if it is not `|`

Comment: You have *undefined behavior* in the code, as you use `answer` before it has been initialized. Uninitialized local variables have an *indeterminate* value, and using them except for initialization leads to said undefined behavior.

Comment: Oh my goodness please format your code properly! :P

Comment: (1) When you write `'|'` it is different to `"|"`.The first is a single character and may be interpreted as a letter or an integer. The second is a string and something that you can compare to another string. (2) Also, if you wish to exit the loop, but not the program, you can use `break`. Using `return` both exits the while loop and the function it resides within, in this case `main`, which cause your whole program to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cin >> answer` will fail when the next non-whitespace character to be read is not a number. You can use that behavior to end the loop.

```
// Break inside the loop.
while( true  )
{
    std::cin>>answer;

    // If there was an error in reading, break out of the loop.
    if ( !std::cin )
       break;

    answers.push_back(answer);

    ++intCounter;

    if(intCounter==2)
    {
        for(int x : answers)
        {
            std::cout<<x<<'\n';
        }
        answers.clear();
        intCounter=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two changes:

1. If your task is to just print numbers you could just use string.
2. You are checking value of answer to `|` before its even been input.
   So

   ```
   #include<iostream>
   #include <vector>
   #include<string>
   using namespace std;
   int main(){

   std::vector<string> answers;
   string answer;
   int intCounter=0;

   while(answers.size()<=2  ){

   std::cin>>answer;
   //after input
   if(answer=="|"){
   return 0;
   }
   answers.push_back(answer);
   ++intCounter;

   if(intCounter==2){
   for(int x=0;x< answers.size();x++){
   std::cout<<answers[x]<<'\n';
   }
   answers.clear();
   intCounter=0;
   }
   }

   return 0;
   }
   ```